# Is there any way to copy and paste the information from excel cell to word with same spacing?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, office-automation

```
With objWord.ActiveDocument
    .Bookmarks("FRlegalentity").Range.Text = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
       .Bookmarks("OffFRPRDate").Range.Text = Range("DA1").Value
           .Bookmarks("FRoffadd").Range.Text = ws.Cells(i, 89).Text
End with
```

I'm trying to copy address of companies from Excel (office address) and paste it into Word. I have used <kbd>ALT+Enter</kbd> in address for each line within cell for location, city, street etc.

My macro is able to paste information but it is creating additional line spacing while pasting information. Can you please help?

Apart from above, for few words while copying and pasting data it is bolding the text which I do not want. Can you please help?

Comment: When pasting such content to Word, ALT-Enter line breaks are converted to paragraph breaks. You have two options: adjust the paragraph before/after spacing; or replace the inserted paragraph breaks with line breaks (Chr(11)).

Comment: thank you I have tried it but it is pasting as below

Comment: 8                Adelaide                Street                     West
 Suite         2003
 Hyd           ON                        M7H                        0A9
 Sec

Comment: Wherever there is a space within same word like 8 Adelide, it is pasting with lot of space between them

Comment: I was able to find a solution for line breaks...can anyone help me with why only few bookmark words are pasted in bold text